# Switching DNS host, is it worth my while?

Tags: dns

I currently get free DNS hosting from [Zoneedit](http://www.zoneedit.com).  I am allowed unlimited monthly queries at no cost and I have no problem with them.

Now, my hosting provider, [Heroku](http://www.Heroku.com) offer an [add-on](http://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns) that lets you use [Zerigo DNS](http://www.zerigo.com/) with considerable ease.  Their free/basic package gives you:

- 1 domain per app
- 10 host records
- 50,000 queries per month

So, it's a fight between **ZoneEdit** with free unlimited monthly queries, and **Zerigo**, who will want $7 a month if the site gets more than 50,000 DNS queries in a month.

**50000 free queries a month** sounds like a lot, but if you break it down, it works out at roughly 1666 a day, which is around 1 a minute.

---

I realise one or two of these questions are subjective but any help with this would really make my decision easier.  Thanks in advance.

### Question 1:

If a user visits the homepage followed by the blog page, does that count as **2 DNS queries**?

### Question 2:

If they then go back to homepage, does that count as **3 queries**?

### Question 3:

Since traffic is low (often less than 10 page visits a day) can we expect to see a performance boost from using Zerigo over ZoneEdit and if so, how can we measure/test it?

### Question 4:

The website in question is for a non-profit organisation who have a very small budget.  They will pay the $7 if I tell them to since they want the site to perform well above all else, but it will mean spending less on other things, like business cards and marketing since the site generates no revenue.  **So, if you were me**, would you switch from having free DNS to something that will potentially cost you $7 (upto $20) a month?

### Question 5:

Would anyone recommend just using Google Public DNS instead as we really do want to keep the costs down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably not, but it depends on your TTL.  If you've got a TTL of, say, 60 seconds then it might.
2. See (1)
3. Somebody would need relative performance metrics for the 2 DNS hosts, from the locations your visitors are at, to work that out
4. Probably not, it would depend on (3) but see too below
5. Your current solution is free - if it's performing acceptably then I'd say there's no need to change it

Comment: thanks a lot, I think I had the wrong impression regarding Google Public DNS (http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq.html#hosting) - I think I will just stick with ZoneEdit :)